# Remove text after <span> and append other text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having a trouble with jQuery trying to remove a text after < span> tag to append other text.

**Example:**

```
<div id="foo-id">  
    <span id="span-id">  
        <i id="icon-id" class="fa fa-square-o"></i>  
    </span> text..here... (this text needs to be removed)
</div>
```

**I know how to append the text:**

```
$('#foo-id').after()[0].append('this is a text');
```

But how can I remove/clear the text after < /span> tag to append a new one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming there are no other text nodes directly within `#foo-id` you could do something like:

```js
$('#foo-id').html(function(){
   return $(this).children(); //only return elements, not text nodes
}).append('Some new text')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo-id">  
    <span id="span-id">  
        <i id="icon-id" class="fa fa-square-o"></i>  
    </span> text..here... (this text needs to be removed)
</div>
```

Comment: superb. i like it, don't misunderstand me asking this, is there any tutorial to study jQuery or Javascript best practice

Comment: @JishnuVS the web is full of tutorials and learning resources

Comment: What a great answer!! Really great! Thank you a lot!! I hope this question/answer gonna help a lot of people!

Comment: do note though that because it replaces the inner html if any event listeners are assigned to the span or icon they would be lost unless they were delegated

Comment: @charlietfl Would chaining `.clone(true)` to `.children()` avoid removing event listeners?

Comment: @guest271314 never even thought of that but yes it does https://jsfiddle.net/mtunkz9k/1/

Comment: @MaxZoom and that was clearly clarified in the assumptions in answer

Answer (score 3):

You can select `.nextSibling` of `#span-id`, set `.textContent` of `#text` node

```js
$("#foo-id #span-id")[0].nextSibling.textContent = "abc123";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo-id">  
    <span id="span-id">  
        <i id="icon-id" class="fa fa-square-o"></i>  
    </span> text..here... (this text needs to be removed)
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tested here and it's working really great!! I did not check your answer as the best because another friend answered first. Thank you a lot! That's another way to do it!! :)

Comment: Actually this answer is better as it covers situation when there is another text before span-id element that should not be removed.