# Toggle text within div based on screen width

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have a dynamic text element after a span something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41112440/remove-text-after-span-and-append-other-text). However I want to hide this content and show it back at certain device with particular width.

For example:

```
<div id="123">
  <span class="glyphicon"></span> 
  some dynamic text
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to find the dynamic text after the `span`, which varies for different pages, and hide it for mobile devices below 480px width and show it again on screens or devices with width of 480px and above.

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: Is it possible to wrap the ending text in its own span? If so, this problem can be solved with a trivial line of CSS. If you can't amend the HTML, then you will need to use ugly JS resize event handlers on the window to determine the screen size and then manually dissect the nodes within that element to find the text and hide them (while storing them in an object so you can put them back in to the DOM if the window becomes large enough again). The latter, aside from being a pain to write, will be exceptionally easy to break and is not ideal for SEO and accessibility.

Comment: It's not possible to wrap the ending text in its own span. I used resize event handlers but its not resolving my issue completely. how do I create variable to use it again when on desktop?